# cURL itself returns 500 but curl-invoking function returns 244

Tags: bash, curl

I've implemented the logic similar to `curl --fail-with-body` to be able to dodge this missing functionality on `curl 7.29.0` as described in https://superuser.com/a/1641410/1673124

```bash
#!/bin/bash

function curlf() {
  local OUTPUT_FILE=$(mktemp)
  local HTTP_CODE=$(curl -v --output $OUTPUT_FILE --write-out "%{http_code}" "$@" | tail -1)

  if [[ ${HTTP_CODE} -lt 200 || ${HTTP_CODE} -gt 299 ]] ; then
    >&2 cat $OUTPUT_FILE
    rm $OUTPUT_FILE
    return $HTTP_CODE
  fi

  cat $OUTPUT_FILE
  rm $OUTPUT_FILE
}
```

This functions is declared in `commons_functions.sh` and here I return `HTTP_CODE`.

Then I import and use this function in file `link_unmatched.sh` to do a POST request as

```bash
#!/bin/bash

source "$(dirname "$0")"/common_functions.sh

curlf -X POST "http://localhost:27527/api/v1/agreement/link-unmatched"

exit_code=$?

exit $exit_code
```

The call fails with `500`, which is expected:

```
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 27527 (#0)
> POST /api/v1/agreement/link-unmatched HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: localhost:27527
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 500 
< Content-Type: application/json
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Wed, 23 Aug 2023 10:11:30 GMT
< Connection: close
< 
{ [data not shown]
100   180    0   180    0     0  13144      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 15000
* Closing connection 0
{"timestamp":"2023-08-23T10:11:30.284+0000","status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","message":"Something went wrong","path":"/api/v1/agreement/link-unmatched"}
```

What is unexpected to me is the result of `echo $?`:

```
$ bash link_unmatched.sh                                                                
$ echo $?                      
244
```

Why does it print 244 and not 500? And what should I do to have 500 in terminal output?

**UPD**
If I modify `curlf()` declaration as

```bash
#!/bin/bash

function curlf() {
  local OUTPUT_FILE=$(mktemp)
  local HTTP_CODE=$(curl -v --output $OUTPUT_FILE --write-out "%{http_code}" "$@" | tail -1)
  echo $HTTP_CODE

  if [[ ${HTTP_CODE} -lt 200 || ${HTTP_CODE} -gt 299 ]] ; then
    >&2 cat $OUTPUT_FILE
    rm $OUTPUT_FILE
    echo $HTTP_CODE
    return $HTTP_CODE
  fi

  cat $OUTPUT_FILE
  rm $OUTPUT_FILE
}
```

and then I execute the same command the output is the following:

```
$ bash link_unmatched_trades.sh
500
500
$ echo $?                      
244
```

Comment: Not sure how Bash does it, but exit codes are _usually_ limited to <256. But why put an HTTP return code in an exit code? What’s good in HTTP (200) isn’t good in a shell (0).

Comment: @Biffen please put this as your answer and I'll accept and upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to "return" (i.e.: `echo`) the result on STDOUT, using the result like `result=$(curlf ...)`. The `return` is very similar to `exit` which is limited to 8 bits.

"500 mod 256" is 244, BTW.

The BASH manual page says (most notably "... *the return value is its* ***least significant 8 bits.***"):

```text
       return [n]
              Causes a function to stop executing and return the value  speci-
              fied  by n to its caller.  If n is omitted, the return status is
              that of the last command executed  in  the  function  body.   If
              return  is  used  outside  a function, but during execution of a
              script by the .  (source) command, it causes the shell  to  stop
              executing  that script and return either n or the exit status of
              the last command executed within the script as the  exit  status
              of  the script.  If n is supplied, the return value is its least
              significant 8 bits.  The return status is non-zero if return  is
              supplied  a  non-numeric argument, or is used outside a function
              and not during execution of a script by . or source.   Any  com-
              mand  associated  with the RETURN trap is executed before execu-
              tion resumes after the function or script.
```

Comment: Thanks, but `exit_code=$(curlf -X POST "http://localhost:27527/api/v1/fx-trade-agreement/link-unmatched-trades") && echo $exit_code` prints 0

Comment: Please check the output running the script with `bash -x`: Does the modified `curlf` *output* the status code?

Comment: ++ local HTTP_CODE=500
++ return 500
+ exit_code=
+ echo
Looks like the status code is not output

Comment: Please re-read the part "**Try to "return" (i.e.: echo) the result on STDOUT**!